# Unable to write data into Hbase using pig + phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-pig, apache-phoenix

I have written a Pig script which takes a date column from one table and write to another table in Hbase :

```
register '/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/lib/phoenix-pig-4.2.0.2.2.9.0-3393.jar';
register '/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-client.jar';
ALL_RECORDS = LOAD 'hbase://table/table_name_1/key_column,column_from' 
USING org.apache.phoenix.pig.PhoenixHBaseLoader('localhost');
ALL_RECORDS_COPY_COL = FOREACH ALL_RECORDS GENERATE key_column, column_from as column_to;
--DUMP ALL_RECORDS_COPY_COL;
STORE ALL_RECORDS_COPY_COL INTO 'hbase://table_name_2/key_column,column_to' using org.apache.phoenix.pig.PhoenixHBaseStorage('localhost','-batchSize 5000');
```

Wen I uncomment dump all record and comment store, it works fine and dumps the data at screen. But if I try to store data hbase using store it says unable to read data from table_name_1/key_column, column_from and does not write anything. Am I making any mistake ?

Comment: What happens if you try to store it in a simple way? For instance using pigstorage?

Comment: I do not want to provide schema, it is a generic script, I have removed `$` sign. The thing is, I have two setups at two different servers, this is working on one and giving issues on another. Strange.

Comment: If you have 2 different environments, it is unfortunate but not strange that they behav differently. To troubleshoot this it would be good to narrow down the problem. Therefore I wonder what happens if you try to store it using pigstorage. -- Something to realize: Pig can say that it has a problem reading the data if actually something else is going wrong (like storing the data).